# Determine if string is newline in C#

Tags: c#, newline

I am somehow unable to determine whether a string is newline or not. The string which I use is read from a file written by Ultraedit using DOS Terminators CR/LF. I assume this would equate to "\r\n" or Environment.NewLine in C#. However , when I perform a comparison like this it always seem to return false :

```
if(str==Environment.NewLine)
```

Anyone with a clue on what's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How are the lines read?  If you're using StreamReader.ReadLine (or something similar), the new line character will not appear in the resulting string - it will be String.Empty or (i.e. "").

Comment: Daniel got the correct answer. File.ReadAllLine won't include the newline into the string. So you should actually check for String.Empty.

Comment: when you use File.ReadAllLines, why do you care about '\n'. You will not get that. Instead you'll get all the lines in a string array split by '\n'. check if File.ReadAllText serves your purpose.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure that the whole string only contains a NewLine and nothing more or less? Have you already tried `str.Contains(Environment.NewLine)`?

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious troubleshooting step would be to check what the value of `str` actually is. Just view it in the debugger or print it out.

Answer (score 2):

Newline is "\r\n", not "/r/n". Maybe there's more than just the newline.... what is the string value in Debug Mode?

You could use the new .NET 4.0 Method:
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace

Answer (score 1):

This is a very valid question.

Here is the answer. I have invented a kludge that takes care of it.

```
static bool StringIsNewLine(string s)
{
    return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) &&
        (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) &&
        (((s.Length == 1) && (s[0] == 8203)) || 
        ((s.Length == 2) && (s[0] == 8203) && (s[1] == 8203)));
}
```

Use it like so:

```
foreach (var line in linesOfMyFile)
{
  if (StringIsNewLine(line)
  {
    // Ignore reading new lines
    continue;
  }

  // Do the stuff only for non-empty lines
  ...
}
```